# How to highlight a row in NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I have NSTableView in my application. right now say is 8 columns by 48 rows.

I have a function that runs a specific a specific column to see wether or not the value in each cell is greater than a certain value. If it is I would like the application to highlight the row.

I did some reading and I am still looking for the functions calls or a process that will let me extract the cells/rows/or rect and let me change the color.

What are the functions and the steps in changing the color of the cells?

Comment: I got a two answers, and I would just like to say if there any way that I can just extract the dataCell from the NSTableView as a NSTextFieldCell, or NSCell, and then just create a custom function to implement the drawing? because NSTextFieldCell & NSCell have their own drawing functions, also it would same me the time to create a separate delegate and a custom cell class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
- [NSTableView selectRowIndexes:byExendingSelection:]
```

[Source](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/selectRowIndexes:byExtendingSelection:)

Comment: okay, it looks i m going to implement my solutions with this. I am going to set the preference so that the user doesn't have the ability to select rows, and I will use this function to select data points in the table that exceeds my condition parameters

Answer (score 3):

To change the color of the cell you can try this method

```
-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
{
   [cell setDrawsBackground:YES];
  if(row==0)
       [cell setBackgroundColor:[NSColor color];
   else if(row==1||row==2)
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[NSColor color];
    else
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[NSColor color];
}
```

this will make your row with different color.

Answer (score 0):

Set a tableView delegate and implement the

```
– tableView:dataCellForTableColumn:row:
```

method.  Then write a custom dataCell class to do the custom drawing.

Comment: is there any way that I can just extract the dataCell from the NSTableView as a NSTextFieldCell, or NSCell, and then just create a custom function to implement the drawing? because NSTextFieldCell & NSCell have their own drawing functions, also it would same me the time to create a separate delegate and a custom cell class

Answer (score 0):

If you extract the data as strings, you can use :-

NSAttributedString

to change the colour of both text and background.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(id)cell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row
```

...gives you the pre-made cell (usually a NSTextFieldCell) which you can then color. Don't need to return it - Apple has already made it and is about to use it, just modify the object as you see fit. Works great.